# TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined Command Handler

Tags: node.js, typeerror

I get this error when I try to make a advance command handler

This is my script:

```
const Discord = require(`discord.js`);
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '!'
const fs = require(`fs`);
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFile = fs.readdirSync('./scripts/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFile){
    const command = require(`./scripts/${file}`);

    client.command.set(command.name, command)
}

client.once('ready', ()=>{
    console.log('Succesfully Started Scriptz')
    client.user.setActivity("Scripts", {
        type: "WATCHING"
    })
})
```

The end part of the client.login I deleted it so you can't get access to my bot

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot an `s` at the end of command.

It should be `client.commands.set` instead.